# How can I pass the name of `ObjectName` like `self.lineEdit_260` as a parameter in a method using python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameter-passing, pyqt5

How can I pass the name of `ObjectName` like `self.lineEdit_260` as a parameter in a method using python 3.4?

```
self.Open_Fan_J104_A_stage_2(no=self.lineEdit_260.text()))

def Open_Fan_J104_A_stage_2(self,no):

    if no=='' and self.lineEdit_247.text()=='':
        print(type(self.lineEdit_260.text()))
        self.start_time=datetime.datetime.now()
        self.lineEdit_260.setText(str(self.start_time))
    elif self.lineEdit_247.text()=='':

        QMessageBox.information(self, 'x')

    else:
        self.lineEdit_260.setText('')
        self.start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.lineEdit_260.setText(str(self.start_time))

    self.lineEdit_247.setText('')
    self.lineEdit_241.setText('')
```

When I run this code:

```
self.pushButton_123.clicked.connect( self.Open_Fan_J104_A_stage_2(no=self.lineEdit_260.text()))
```

> TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Comment: It is an `attribute` of the `instance`, why do you wanna pass it ?

Comment: I have many line edit and each one take vaIue when press on it's own button so i want to pass the name of lineedit function  to control each one by it's button

Answer (score 0):

I think, the `Open_Fan_J104_A_stage_2` expects a `callable` and since there was a lack of information. So try,

```
self.Open_Fan_J104_A_stage_2(lambda: self.lineEdit_260.text()))
```